# Second for loop will not trigger in my $scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function that if it works should assign a created div(task tile) to the right user. Check this link for a visual of the application -> http://gyazo.com/539abe727f0c77be39ac85ee46f4c395
As you can see now the task just show randomly on the grid.

This is part of the code from my app.js:

```
//Link user to a task
    $scope.linkTaskToUser = function() {
        console.log("Logging root scope ", $rootScope);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.taskInfo.length; i++) { //Doorlopen van alle taken

            console.log('Logging scope taskInfo -->' , $scope.taskInfo);

            for (var j = 0; j < $rootScope.users.length; j++) { //Doorlopen van alle users
                console.log('fasfsda -->');
                if ($rootScope.users[j].email == $scope.taskInfo[i].email) {
                    console.log('fasfsda1111'); //Vergelijken van emails tussen taken en users
                    $scope.taskInfo[i].top = $rootScope.users[j].offsetTop; //Top waarde van de taak gelijkstellen aan de offset van de user
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is now that it will log the 2 first logs but it will not log the third one in the second for loop mean that the second for loop is not being executed.

The idea of this function is that it will loop through all my task and all of my users then it will compare the email of the $rootScope.users to that of the $scope.taskInfo and if there is a match it will set the top value of the $scope.taskInfo equal to that of the $rootScope.users offsetTop, so that the tasks will show on the correct row.

I hope someone can help me out (if you need more code to better understand the situation let me know)

Comment: Can you paste what your data looks like?

Comment: What's the value of users.length.

Comment: @MathewBerg -> http://gyazo.com/539abe727f0c77be39ac85ee46f4c395

Comment: @NickBailey, it doen not log so I can't see it but I know I have 9 users in the db

Comment: Can you paste your two arrays somewhere? Create a jsFiddle with the issue.

Comment: Well, log it or breakpoint it

Comment: @NickBailey, i do log it but it won't show because it does not come in the second for loop

Comment: @MathewBerg, its difficult to create a jsFiddle because there is a lot of code in my app.js (thats why i didn't create one in the first place)

Comment: You can create one with just this loop though.

Comment: Log it before you enter the second loop.

Comment: @NickBailey, ok. It returns 0

Comment: Well there's your problem. You aren't adding any users to that collection.

Comment: @MathewBerg -> here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/GY22/312t5uwq/1/. not sure it will help

Comment: Just create one of JUST this function with the data. No need to paste the whole app.

Comment: @NickBailey, ok so the users are not getting passed from my directive. how to active the directive in my function?

Comment: @MathewBerg, here http://jsfiddle.net/GY22/312t5uwq/4/ . But you won't have any use for it because the whole function is based on code from the whole app ..

Comment: users in db is irrelevant... problem tells me that `$rootScope.users` has no length. Where is it created?

Comment: The logic if your loop is failing, so paste the loop (like you did) but also set the taskInfo and users.

Comment: @charlietfl, $rootScope.users is create in my custom directive

Comment: @GY22 here: http://jsfiddle.net/8d4k8yev/ paste in what you have for users and taskInfo

Comment: It's fairly simple to inspect the $rootScope object in this code.... look at it and see if users property exists, is an array and has length. We can't do that for you without a demo that replicates problem. Creating users in directive really doesn't make much sense anywy, you need a users service probably

Comment: @charlietfl: data in my $rootScope is present -> http://gyazo.com/d3c8dcd950077301254cb6d2a2add3a3

Comment: @Mathew Berg: i used your jsFiddle want don't see any changes ...

Comment: Literally paste your array data in for $scope.taskInfo and $rootScope.users

Comment: @charlietfl: the users exist but apparently only get loaded after the custom directive is executed

Comment: be aware that the object you log is a reference...not a snapshot. So the users could be added after your code above runs and console will reflect that update. Really sounds more like a process flow problem.

Comment: @charlietfl: ok got it. but how to work around this or fix it ? (sorry for the silly question, still new at this...)

Comment: Need to see directive as well as this function. Suggest you start new question this is getting far too long...delete this one

Comment: @charlietfl: ok just made a new question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477822/users-exist-but-only-load-after-a-custom-directive-is-executed